# PFSense VLAN's - clients cant access devices on a defined VLAN

Tags: vlan, pfsense

I'm having an issue setting up pfSense with VLAN's, basically, the pfSense boxes can ping the devices on the tagged vlan, but clients routing through pfSense cannot.

There are two Cisco SG500 switches, referred to as switch0 and switch1 below:

Switch0 - pfsense0 and pfsense1 are connected to this switch, dedicated adapters with vlan's defined under vlans and interface assignments, firewall rules currently set to allow everything, no blocks.
switch1 (LAG between switch0 <-> switch1; set to trunk 1U, 100T, 400T, 500T, 600T), management IP on switch1 is set to 192.168.1.100, vlan 100

pfsense0 and pfsense1, can ping, traceroute and telnet to 192.168.1.100 -- so I don't believe it's an issue with the VLAN configuration on the switches...

However, clients routing through pfsense0/pfsense1 (they're in a CARP, but I don't believe that has any impact here but I'm mentioning it just in case), cannot access 192.168.1.100. If I do a ping, it times out, traceroute gets stuck at the pfsense box. I can do a packet capture, but I'm not seeing any errors, I can see the packets, but no rejection/ack/etc.

Any idea what would cause pfSense to not route packets from clients to vlan100? I originally thought it was a configuration issue with the switches, but because each pfsense box can access that IP, I believe it's an issue on the pfSense side. Probably, or hopefully, something simple.

Comment: I just realized the device I'm having a hard time accessing, doesn't allow a default gateway to be specified. The switch is an SFE2010P. I believe this may be the problem.